# How to add variation details to product variations in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am currently using WooCommerce REST API v3 to get product details. But when it comes to variable products , variation id is only provided by the API.
I want a method by which variation price(regular and sale) and variation image are inserted inside the API response along with variation id.
So that i can directly access these parameters without making a second API call to get these details which takes time.
Current response:

variations:

```
Array(3)
0: 565
1: 564
2: 563
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the direct answer but got a workaround. I now use prime_html to display sale price, regular price in my app.
I anyone have the same problem add below code to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', '__return_true' );
if (!function_exists('my_commonPriceHtml')) {

function my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price) {
    $html_price = '<p class="price">';
    //if product is in sale
    if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price != 0)) {
        $discount=  round((($regular_price - $sale_price)/($regular_price)) * 100,0);
        $html_price = '<h3>&#8377;'.round($sale_price,0). '</h3>'  ; ;
        $html_price .= '<del>'. wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
        $html_price .=   '<h4>'.$discount .'%&nbsp;' . OFF .'</h4>' ;
    }

    //not is sale
    else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price != 0)) {
        $html_price .=   wc_price($regular_price) ;
    }



    return $html_price;
}

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_simple_product_price_html', 100, 2);

function my_simple_product_price_html($price, $product) {
if ($product->is_type('simple')) {
    $regular_price = $product->regular_price;
    $sale_price = $product->sale_price;
    $price_amt = $product->price;
    return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
} else {
    return $price;
}
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_price_html($price, $variation) {
$variation_id = $variation->variation_id;
//creating the product object
$variable_product = new WC_Product($variation_id);

$regular_price = $variable_product->regular_price;
$sale_price = $variable_product->sale_price;
$price_amt = $variable_product->price;

 return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
 }

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_minmax_price_html($price, $product) {
$variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min', true);
$variation_min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);

if (($variation_min_price == $variation_min_regular_price) && ($variation_max_price == $variation_max_regular_price)) {
    $html_min_max_price = $price;
} else {

    $discount=  round((($variation_min_regular_price - $variation_min_price)/($variation_min_regular_price)) * 100,0);
    $html_price = '<p class="price">';
    $html_price =   '<h3>&#8377;'.round($variation_min_price,0). '</h3>'  ;
    $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($variation_min_regular_price) .  '</del>';
    $html_price .=   '<h4>'.$discount .'%&nbsp;' . OFF .'</h4>' ;
    $html_min_max_price = $html_price;
}

return $html_min_max_price;
}
?>
```